# JavaScript issue when logged in

Tags: bug, comments, user-accounts, javascript

I'm getting a cross-browser issue with the JavaScript on Stack Overflow, which wasn't happening yesterday, and which clearing my cache and switching from Chrome to Firefox didn't fix. The error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

It is triggered within this part of the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
             StackExchange.gps.init(true);
        });
    </script>
```

Which is at line 48 on the main HTML. Further digging revealed line 166 in `full.js`.

I can't do the following things right now:

- Open my notifications
- Comment on anything
- Vote on anything
- Add a second answer to anything

This error only occurs if I'm logged in. If I answer anything, Stack Overflow asks me to prove I'm not a robot before I can post my answer. Also, the preview box doesn't show up for my answer, or the rich text editing panel. The issue also shows up on `http://cooking.stackexchange.com/`, and probably the other Stack Exchange sites as well, but not on `meta.stackoverflow.com`. I have not yet tested it on other computers, though I intend to later this afternoon.

How can this issue be fixed?

Additional information: The primary difference seems to be that Stack Overflow loads `full.js` from `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb` and Meta Stack Overflow loads from `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb`. Other Stack Exchange sites seem to load from the same place as Stack Overflow. Could the issue be here somewhere?

More observations: The `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb` script seems to contain lots of what looks like gibberish. Blocks of code like

```
entheCou.ivaplivalnp;btagec.SueClite){! an))a.parent(tec:$('inpuass("heCs() 
{taror,T/ion(udClass(="vt"><i r2n ind("fav
en"fav
en"fav
en"fav
i,T/!=cti="text"fav
```

This starts happening at line 166. Everything above this line looks normal, below this line, it looks like the code went through a blender, was then fed to a hungry [raccoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raccoon), and finally scooped up three days later and pasted into my browser. I have no idea what to do with this.

I am hitting the NetDNA Virginia Datacenter. Also, if I change the value of `v` in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) (that is, `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fa`), I get what looks like valid code that is, on brief inspection, identical to the code at `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb`.

Comment: No repro with Safari 6.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.8.3. Testing with FF...

Comment: No repro with FF 20.0 on Mac OSX 10.8.3. I would test chrome, but I don't have it installed. Is it possible that you have a browser extension (such as NoScript) that may be causing an issue?

Comment: I doubt it. It was working yesterday and now works on none of my browsers (even tested in IE, which never gets used or changed). I noticed that line 166 in `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb` ends with `c==$(this).ext(),10typ)ataTegister)});p()},l=function(d){a>`, while the same line from the other source looks like not terrible error. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100102/163863) information (specifically, I think, which CDN you're hitting).

Comment: As an aside: the `?v=` does not affect what JavaScript you're getting from the server. It's just a cache breaker [based on the file contents](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-05/#comment-59013), ensuring your browsers loads a new version whenever the code on the server has changed. When the file contents have changed, the value for `?v=` is changed in the HTML, making the browser see a new URL it has not cached before.

Comment: Maybe it's not __supposed__ to affect it, but based on looking side by side at the content given by two urls with different `?v=` values, it most certainly can. Changing the `?v=` value goes from horribly mangled javascript to the correct javascript. Interestingly, clearing my cache results in different mangled javascript, but still only for the 'bad' value of `?v=`. (Got a bunch of yen symbols in it this time.)

Comment: Testing from home, I don't get this bug, but I'm hitting the New York data center. Would anyone hitting the NetDNA Virginia data center be able to check this bug?