# CSS for Stack Overflow didn't load

Tags: discussion, design, internet-explorer

I originally thought this was a mobile-theme related issue, but it is not. The css of the page does not load.

I guess I could clear my browser's cache. Is there any other option?

[image: screenshot]

**Edit**: I do not have the "full site" option at the very bottom :(

[image: screenshot]

**Edit2:** this is not an issue with the mobile theme. Here's my data according to the requests from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads)

> **Samble CDN file**: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=d5ace739b006
>   **My IP**: 186.48.230.46
>   **Tracing route** to sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com [69.174.57.102]
>   over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
> 1    21 ms    15 ms    25 ms  pucor1bras1.antel.net.uy [200.40.21.7]
>    2    16 ms    16 ms    18 ms  ibb2cor1-7-2-93.antel.net.uy [200.40.21.81]
>    3    20 ms    16 ms    16 ms  ibb2agu1-1-3.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.73]
>    4    29 ms    56 ms    21 ms  ibr3agu1-p1.antel.net.uy [200.40.18.38]
>    5   167 ms   159 ms   159 ms  So5-2-0-0-grtbueba2.red.telefonica-wholesale.net.7.16.84.in-addr.arpa [84.16.7.57]
>    6   156 ms   159 ms   163 ms  Xe5-1-3-0-grtmiabr7.red.telefonica-wholesale.net.125.142.94.in-addr.arpa [94.142.125.122]
>    7   200 ms   209 ms   186 ms  Xe-0-0-2-0-grtwaseq3.red.telefonica-wholesale.net [94.142.124.109]
>    8   198 ms     *      196 ms  213.140.55.90
>    9   199 ms   197 ms   204 ms  po2-20G.ar4.DCA3.gblx.net [67.16.133.82]
>   10   222 ms   195 ms   194 ms  PACKETEXCHANGE-LTD.TenGigabitEthernet2-4.ar4.DCA3.gblx.net    [64.211.83.106]
>   11   205 ms   197 ms   197 ms  te4-7.cr1.was2.us.packetexchange.net [69.174.120.125]
>   12   180 ms   206 ms   188 ms  69.174.31.2
>   13   194 ms   192 ms   221 ms  69.174.57.102
>
> Trace complete.
>
> **Tracert** to the origin:
>   Tracing route to sstatic.net [64.34.119.12]
>   over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
> 1    29 ms    33 ms    38 ms  pucor1bras1.antel.net.uy [200.40.21.7]
>    2    38 ms    19 ms    16 ms  ibb2cor2-7-2-93.antel.net.uy [200.40.21.209]
>    3    66 ms    93 ms    73 ms  ibb2uni2-1-3.antel.net.uy [200.40.16.98]
>    4    46 ms    24 ms    20 ms  ibr3uni1-p2.antel.net.uy [200.40.22.166]
>    5   214 ms   224 ms   198 ms  so-3-1-0.mia11.ip4.tinet.net [77.67.78.189]
>    6   221 ms   253 ms   224 ms  xe-0-2-0.nyc20.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.183.2]
>    7   301 ms   291 ms   304 ms  peer1-gw.ip4.tinet.net [77.67.70.194]
>    8   230 ms   225 ms   223 ms  10ge.xe-0-0-0.nyc-telx-dis-2.peer1.net [216.187.115.182]
>    9   263 ms   204 ms   199 ms  oc48-po3-0.nyc-75bre-dis-1.peer1.net [216.187.115.134]
>   10   209 ms   208 ms   207 ms  gwny01.stackoverflow.com [64.34.41.58]
>   11   202 ms   217 ms   221 ms  stackoverflow.com [64.34.119.12]
>
> Trace complete.
>   **Datacenter:** Miami

Comment: Why is clearing your cache not the only option?

Comment: This looks like the css isn't loading rather than being stuck in the mobile theme.

Comment: at the very bottom the mobile link appears as selected, not a link

Comment: I'm on a mobile device and CSS is missing in mobile view e.g. for SO.

Comment: They have fixed a few issues at the CDN provider; can you confirm this isn't happening anymore, or are you still having problems?

Comment: Aha! I knew something was going on... I sent an email and they answered saying I shouldn't be sending email to them... Nobody told me they did have a problem... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem: I had disabled HTTP 1.1 on IE9 when working on something else and I forgot to turn it back on. Once it was back on the problem went away.

Answer (score 12):

This is not the mobile theme, the static resources aren't getting loaded.  Try a hard refresh, if that doesn't work, try clearing your cache.  You might be having problems reaching the cdn,.  There are some troubleshooting steps [posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92452/140548) that you could try if that is the case.

Comment: I guess you're right... I did pay attention to that or even try to debug the css load... there's actually no css at all... I did try to clear the cache but still facing the same problem... I'm in Uruguay (south america btw)

Comment: Did you do anything with cdn that I suggested?

Comment: I pasted my data in the body of the question... what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried all the regular things: Clearing browser data (cache and history), testing other networks and even a hotspot, hard refresh (Shift + F5), rebooting, disabling my antivirus; none of these had any effect. My problem wasn’t just with SO, but with other sites as well, and from various countries. I was surprised to realise the solution: What *did* make the difference, was disabling Adblock. I tried reloading the page after reenabling AdBlock, and the CSS was again not loading.

Solution № 3: Disable Adblock. This is how you do it:

- At the top of you browser, there is an icon displaying a stop sign with a stopping hand embossed on top of it. If your Adblock is running, the stop sign is red.
- Click the icon, then choose either ‘Pause on this site’ or ‘Pause on all sites’; the sign will turn green with a thumbs up symbol embossed.
- Refresh the page regularly (F5), or if that doesn’t work, do a hard refresh (Shift+F5).

As commented by @Markus Pscheidt, if this method works, one can open the same menu as described above, and select ‘Don’t run on this page’, which disables AdBlock for the entire *site*.

Comment: Ad-Block was the culprit

Comment: Question I have now, which I haven’t had the time to go into, is how I filter sites to be whitelisted. Yes, it is possible to select ‘Dont’t run on this page’, but I am assuming that would only select that specific URL, and sites like SO have probably in the tens of thousands of individual pages, so that is not an acceptable solution. I wish there was a ‘Don’t run on this site’ option as well.

Comment: Deactivating Ad-Block for the site does indeed work for all pages of the site.

Comment: Whoulda thunk‽ Maybe someone needs to instruct them on their terminology. I’ll update my answer as per your reply.