# Why sometimes SO is loaded only in HTML view?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, page-load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [CSS for Stack Overflow didn't load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/css-for-stack-overflow-didnt-load)

Sometimes ***SO*** website is loaded only in ***HTML* view** like this:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX53q.png]
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZcN0.png]

I face this problem at least once a week! It does not happen due to my *Internet Speed* is low, because when this problem occur at that time the [*YouTube*](http://www.youtube.com/) or [*Google-Image*](http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi) work fine.

Comment: Looks like the CSS files were not loaded correctly... A refresh of the page with `CTRL+F5` should solve this...

Comment: It does not solve the problem even after refreshing too many times. But after few time (approx. 15-20 minutes) it load perfectly.

Comment: Are you behind some sort of proxy?  Are there some limitations in your office with regard to what sites you are allowed to view?  This might also be causing problems...

Comment: No. There are no limitations in my office. May be this occur as per [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/css-for-stack-overflow-didnt-load/102270#102270).

Comment: Some browsers have difficulties with refresh in that they don't reload all files. I distinctly remember Firefox doing this in the past: it never reloaded CSS files on Ctrl+F5, even if the files were changed on the server. And I had to clear the cache manually and hit Ctrl+F5 before the new CSS got loaded. Maybe that will help here?

Comment: Also, @MrLister, I think some browsers might not really ignore the cache on Ctrl+F5 but merely ask the server if things have changed, where the server says `304 Not Modified`. (Using `If-Modified-Since` or `Etag` headers; other browsers such as Chrome do that for a regular refresh). Also, on Stack Exchange sites many non-essential resources are loaded using script. It seems some (if not all) browsers tend to reload "regular" resources when using Ctrl+F5, but then still fall back to cached things when scripts start making request too. (See `StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers` in the HTML.)

Comment: And for Chrome: [Chrome Forced Refresh does not ignore cache](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44122).

Comment: As an aside, your (I'd say *excessive*) formatting is used as an example in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/if-it-is-in-italic-it-must-be-pretty