# Pretty unnecessary use of italics

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)

There *seems* to be a *trend* recently to *"italicise" words* like [in this *suggested* edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/328656) for example.

Using *italic* to highlight something specific ***makes*** sense, but using it for all the *libraries*, *tools*, *services* etc. seems unnecessary, if not *counterproductive*.

Is it *only* me? Should we reject *those* edits as too minor? *Invalid*?

Are there any formatting guidelines?

Comment: Ick. That's all I can say.

Comment: **Which** is **worse, that** or the **non**-strategic **bolding**?

Comment: If it's italic, it must be *sexy*. Oh là là!

Comment: [Oh, for Pete's sake, after all that trouble I went to calling people out on using inline code to highlight words.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)

Comment: I have *edited* the post to remove the **italics**

Comment: It's http://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056 - he's provided endless edits changing keywords to italics.

Comment: Yeah, we were [talking about that just the other day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140947/quality-of-suggested-edit-reviews).

Comment: Is there anything we can do to educate those who received the privilege to evaluate suggested edits? Because I don't see a way to poke them at the moment with something like "Hey, you accepted this, but you really want to reject this the next time because of..."

Comment: The "italian" user has 4 out his 6 recent suggestions rejected, hopefully he will get 7 days ban soon from suggesting new edits and finally try to figure out why.

Comment: @Bart - make that a separate [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah, I might a bit later on when I have some time. But I have no clue yet how not to let that end up in a mess.

Comment: @Bart - agreed. Some sort of flag on the suggested edit page? If N people subsequently flag as "invalid" then it's treated as a reject wrt to the auto ban?

Comment: @ChrisF Yeah, but then the suggested edits should hang around for a while even after acceptance/rejection for them to be evaluated somehow. To evaluate the evaluated so to say...

Comment: @Bart - they already do - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/328816. You'd just need a page that listed recent accepted edits and buttons to say "OK" or "Not OK". You could even penalise the approvers (by temporarily taking away their approval rights) if they get too many "wrong".

Comment: @ChrisF Ah, that might work. When I get back tonight I can do a writeup for a feature request. If anyone else feels like it in the mean time, go ahead.

Comment: @Bart - I felt like it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141100/have-an-edit-approval-review-page-so-we-correct-incorrect-approvals-and-educate

Comment: Much better than code markup on random words at least

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for that. :)

Comment: And also: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).

Comment: Oh! Now you will not face such problem (too minor edits) from me. Thanks..

Comment: Most answers seem to be focusing on the suggested edits part. Any note on the formatting guidelines, anyone? I also see folks adding lots of code or emphasis to their own posts.

Comment: Argh, why the title edit? I trained myself to search Meta for "pretty" when I needed to find this post, and now it doesn't work anymore. @razlebe

Comment: @PopularDemand Fixed for you. Though that was a *pretty unnecessary* edit, too.

Comment: @razlebe haha, thanks. I would've done something like that myself but I was afraid there was some reason for the edit I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*Invalid*. Adding *italics* to random *words* seems to *be* a new *trend* (or is it just that one guy?). I've just rejected a bunch of them, though I seem to have been too late for many. This is a variation from the many suggestions that add `code markup` to `random` words. Or **abuse**  **bold** markup.

### Use that Reject button!

Comment: Very true, I also reject tons of those hoping the one who suggested will take a look in the rejection reason and learn from his mistake.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with @Gilles of course: random italic and bold text is bad. Reject edits diligently, please :-). On a more general note:

---

For some reason even the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold) speaks of *italic* and **bold**. However, the Stack Exchange engine knows better, and translates this nicely to `<em>phasized` and `<strong>ly emphasized`.

Emphasis is meant to make something **stand out** in a post, thus improving readability of the post. Removing- and especially *adding* emphasis to someone else's post seems hard, but is in many cases very reasonable... and in many it's not. I trust those with enough rep and powers to (dis)approve edits, using their (in this case probably often subjective) judgement wisely to reject or approve on a case by case basis.

**Suggestion:** Having said that, it would be nice if the markdown help mentions that italics and bold translate to certain levels of emphasis, and are meant for just that: *emphasis*.

Comment: Unfortunately there `are` far *too* many high-rep users who accept edits **where** the emphasis is completely unnecessary or wrong and does nothing to help the post. Just now I had to once again edit such a case after it got accepted right in front of me. :s

Comment: @Bart Aye, and like I said in the first bit of my post: rejecting bad edits is a good thing. But given that it apparently is the SE "Summer of Love" I figured I'd also add some thoughts and a suggestion on how we can spread the word a bit more, and get those editors "in" on our rules and how we'd like to see bold and italics used.