# Stack Overflow is displayed incorrectly

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS for Stack Overflow didn't load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/css-for-stack-overflow-didnt-load)

[image]

I don't know why it is not displaying correctly. This site (meta.stackoverflow.com) looks normal. It's just the regular https://stackoverflow.com/ that looks funny.

Also, I tried it in both Internet Explorer and Firefox.  Same result in both.

Comment: [dup 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141074/why-sometimes-so-is-loaded-only-in-html-view)
[dup 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102257/css-for-stack-overflow-didnt-load)

Comment: neither of these solve my issue, got any others?

Comment: I have to say, I like this retro style. Internet used to be so pure and simple.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - and poorly aligned

Comment: @Gnoupi that's what tables were for my friend!

Comment: @Gnoupi Yes... having no CSS styling has a few downsides

Comment: Are you getting 404/etc errors from cdn.sstatic.net? That's where the CSS/images are loaded from, if you can't get those you'll get a page like you're seeing here

Comment: I get this once in a while when I'm on hotel Wifi or otherwise shady connections. Sometimes the full gamut of CSS/JS etc. doesn't load. Refresh almost always fixes it.

Comment: @BenBrocka well, kindof, I get a bing search page...

Comment: I found the problem, some idiot at our network decided to use a public IP range for our internal network at my work... needless to say, this cdn.sstatic.net site is on that range.  I will have a static route added.  Does anyone know the IP address range for their webservers?