# SO showing up as all text when I refresh

Tags: bug

Stack Overflow keeps showing up as all text when I refresh the page.  Undoubtedly this is in part because I'm on a less than awesome connection, however it doesn't happen as I navigate from page to page; it only seems to be happening when I hit F5 to refresh a page.

I'm wondering if this is purely a server side issue or if it's at all a client side problem that I could address (possibly by using a different browser?)

Comment: Similar perhaps? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141074/why-sometimes-so-is-loaded-only-in-html-view

Comment: @Bart Maybe.  The post that that's marked a duplicate of is definitely a different issue though.