# cdn.sstatic.net cannot be accessed in China

Tags: support, cdn

By watching Web Inspector of Safari, it is observed that cdn.sstatic.net seems to be blocked in China, rendering stack exchange sites virtually unusable. And it could be accessed by routing the ip address through VPN manually.

The ISP is China Unicom Beijing province network.

EDIT:

My route:

```
netstat -nr |grep 190
190.93.244.58      ppp0               UHS             0      173    ppp0
```

With VPN routing:

```
traceroute 190.93.244.58
traceroute to 190.93.244.58 (190.93.244.58), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  THIS IS MY VPN PPP IP ADDRESS (REDACTED)  632.146 ms  278.306 ms  507.538 ms
 2  unassigned.calpop.com (64.27.23.1)  406.791 ms *  260.980 ms
 3  unassigned.calpop.com (64.27.16.142)  881.587 ms  351.883 ms  506.606 ms
 4  tg1-8--200.br01.lsan.acedc.net (69.27.173.37)  375.675 ms  286.618 ms  232.166 ms
 5  xe-2-0-7.ar2.lax2.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.213)  770.909 ms  514.690 ms  383.999 ms
 6  ae1-40g.cr1.lax2.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.88)  584.128 ms  579.189 ms  679.863 ms
 7  vlan-73.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.125.241)  257.999 ms  451.926 ms  465.158 ms
 8  * as13335.xe-12-0-3.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.124.118)  251.144 ms  522.976 ms
 9  190.93.244.58 (190.93.244.58)  388.556 ms  359.830 ms  348.917 ms
```

Without VPN routing (190.93.247.58 was not routed through VPN):

```
$ traceroute cdn.sstatic.net
traceroute: Warning: cdn.sstatic.net has multiple addresses; using 190.93.247.58
traceroute to sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net (190.93.247.58), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.549 ms  58.125 ms  2.584 ms
 2  114.248.224.1 (114.248.224.1)  28.264 ms  144.454 ms  60.938 ms
 3  61.148.174.229 (61.148.174.229)  69.963 ms  960.715 ms *
 4  61.148.155.253 (61.148.155.253)  132.056 ms  43.826 ms  286.267 ms
 5  * 202.96.12.13 (202.96.12.13)  206.717 ms  23.343 ms
 6  219.158.101.122 (219.158.101.122)  131.004 ms  192.286 ms  127.349 ms
 7  * 219.158.3.62 (219.158.3.62)  313.897 ms  238.912 ms
 8  219.158.19.194 (219.158.19.194)  195.688 ms  135.694 ms  127.288 ms
 9  219.158.102.158 (219.158.102.158)  538.262 ms *  388.867 ms
10  sl-st51-la-.sprintlink.net (144.223.54.221)  311.209 ms  511.195 ms  305.902 ms
11  144.232.0.194 (144.232.0.194)  398.987 ms  479.183 ms  558.493 ms
12  ae-0.gtt.lsanca03.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (198.173.172.6)  337.466 ms  317.595 ms *
13  * ae1-80g.cr1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.129)  416.658 ms
    ae0-50g.cr1.lax2.us.nlayer.net (69.31.124.84)  328.737 ms
14  ae2-50g.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.142)  394.454 ms
    vlan-73.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.125.241)  258.389 ms
    ae2-50g.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.142)  318.648 ms
15  as13335.xe-11-0-6.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.125.106)  336.138 ms  427.999 ms
    as13335.xe-9-0-7.ar1.lax1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.127.62)  409.203 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
```

And all the ways down repeating * * * without ending, really mad.

EDIT2:
`traceroute` stopped at the 64th hop, which is OS X default, IMHO.

Comment: Can you do a `tracert  cdn.sstatic.net` with and wthout VPN to see if it is a local isue to your ISP?

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225681/167646) help you?

Comment: It looks like the packets stay in sunny California...

Comment: It looks like the sunny California was not blocked, hence the actual blocked IP range was the cdn's. Evil resides in the Great Firewall of China.

Comment: Related [What else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)