# Cannot login SO from China

Tags: support, login

I'm from China and using [goagent](https://code.google.com/p/goagent/) to access some blocked websites.
But recently I can't login to SO.

[image]

As you can see, connection to `cdn.sstatic.net` timed out.
But if I use goagent to direct connection to `cdn.sstatic.net`
(Edit: Explanation-connection will be directed to the goagent server hosted on Google App Engine, and the data would be sent from GAE to bypass the blocking)

[image]
Because it uses https so I can't use goagent to access it.

Tried ping `cdn.sstatic.net` on both my Linux system and Windows system, 100% packet loss.

Maybe you'd wonder then how am I posting this question? I logged into SO while I was in US and the cookie's still there. I don't even dare to logout because I probably can't login again.

Can someone help? As far as I know, many, many Chinese programmers rely on goagent to access blocked websites and it'll make their life much harder if they can't login to SO :-(

Comment: Maybe it's related to the login recently moving to https and the "goagent" can't handle it just yet?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes I guess so.

Comment: @AdityaPatil I'm sorry but I don't see your logic. The majority of the people who'd be able to help with my programming-related questions doesn't belong to the 33% population.

Comment: @octref India and china have most developers.

Comment: @octref I just wanted to say that don't break laws and rules, that would only create problems. It was just a suggestion, it's up to you what you do.

Comment: @AdityaPatil When did our government stand on the moral high ground by blocking facebook, twitter, wikipedia, wordpress, even GOOGLE and now even SO? And why would browsering-SO-to-learn-programming be comparable to pirating-some-xyz-software?

Comment: @AdityaPatil Yes, but most of the good developers in India and China use SO MUCH more frequently. In most of the Chinese forums, you can't get a reply in 1 day.

Comment: @octref I think I need to explain my though because no one here is understanding what I want to say.1.blocking good sites(like google & SO) is not good, whichever country does that. 2.What I hear about chinese govt, they can be very cruel to law breakers 3.I am not comparing SO with piracy. 4.chinese firewall and the people working behind it are very good, my ethical hacker friends tell me that, so your efforts to bypass it won't last very long. 5. so it would be better that you find local solutions, so you won't be in any trouble. 6.I don't intend to blame anybody here.

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225966/cdn-sstatic-net-cannot-be-accessed-in-china and the [What else do I need part](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: @AdityaPatil Sorry i misunderstood you. But to my knowledge, programmers in big Chinese tech companies like Ali, Tencent, Baidu are also bypassing the blocking. If you just bypass the blocking to access Google and SO I'm 100% sure it's fine. They just don't want most people to easily access some "sensitive content".

Comment: @octref If it's so, then good luck.I am not a very good programmer, but probably, it's problem `goagent`.Have you tried reporting bug or contacting the developers? also maybe there are other apps like goagent, there are always hidden gems to be found.

Comment: After looking through this question, I looked in to GFC(great firewall of china) and got through this [link](http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) and it seems they allow stackoverflow.  I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @Praveen This is the problem. http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=cdn.sstatic.net

Comment: @AdityaPatil Thanks, but I'm sure it's not goagent's problem. I mentioned in the question I can't ping to cdn.sstatic.net.

Answer (score 20):

Sorry guys. The problem probably does **not** come from China's web blocking.
The APCN2 submarine cable was broken, and, as a result, some websites became unreachable or really slow in many Asia countries.
[News here](http://www.rappler.com/technology/news/54323-damaged-apcn2-internet-connectivity)
Other news say the cable would be fixed before Apr, 4th.
And today, Apr 4th, My computer could connect to `cdn.sstatic.net` without problem.

Thanks for the attention and help.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: That explains _quite a bit_ of things I was seeing too (coming from The Philippines and a PLDT subscriber)

Answer (score 5):

I can't give you a definite solution, but I can offer a *possible* work-around. [Hola](https://hola.org/) seems to be working for other users that have reported issues accessing the CDN from Mainland China.

That's .. unfortunately our reply to most cases like this since it's not possible to troubleshoot this issue from *your* side to see what works - just continue trying a variety of proxies until you get one that works.

The reason I've been recommending Hola to people is the option it gives you to change VPNs on the fly. If local servers don't get through, UK ones may, or even US/AU/PH/HK. Your best bet is probably the HK pool, when it's available.

(Disclaimer, I'm an avid user of Hola, and this is my personal recommendation. There is no relationship between Hola and Stack Exchange.)

Comment: This is clearly a bug with China, bug reports should be send here: http://www.mps.gov.cn/n16/index.html

Comment: I did not know a bug tracker for that existed.

Comment: Love that the chinese ministry for public security website has an image that bounces around the window :P

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. I spent some time investigating the issue and [this](http://www.rappler.com/technology/news/54323-damaged-apcn2-internet-connectivity) might be the cause. According to reports the cable should be fixed by Apr, 4th. If the problem would disappear after Apr, 4th I'll update my question here. Thanks for the recommendation, although I've just bought a VPS and set it up as a VPN to connect to SO.

Comment: @Yannis Bug confirmed. I'm using the newest 2014.4 version :-)

Comment: Hola is not working for me in Pu'er, Yunnan as of the end of May 2015.