# Eek! Chat FAQ formatting gone

Tags: bug, status-deferred, chat, ssl

So I was going to read the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) and saw this:

[image: Formatting]

The formatting looks completely messed up. Is it just me?

**UPDATE:** This only happens on the https version of the page. On http it displays just fine. I checked my browser console and discovered this (and many similar) error:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.stackoverflow.com.css?v=2a7d8c6bd8da': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

I think that's what's causing this.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: @juergend: See update.

Comment: I can reproduce here.

Comment: A temporary solution for this for chrome is https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en or better be lazy and click this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: https is not supported in Stack Exchange. It's planned but might take long years. Simply do not browse such pages but rather only the ordinary `http://` version of the site.

Comment: What Shadow Wizard said. We do not support https on all parts of our site yet, so you should expect to have things break if you use https everywhere.