# Stack Exchange sites fail to load CSS and several JavaScript resources with AdBlock enabled

Tags: support, design, javascript

With the [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) add-on, this is what Stack Exchange sites look like:

[image: adblock enabled]

And there are lot of errors in the console, like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
  at 51978760?noredirect=1:45
```

There are several resources blocked, for instance:

- https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=98d2853eec34
- https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=1694918621dc
- https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary-unified.css?v=6df0fe83c631
- https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9
- https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=04d772c81312
- https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d

When AdBlock is disabled, all these resources are loading fine.

Comment: It looks like all CSS and all JavaScript is blocked. What do you expect the SE dev team to do? It is explicit that it needs javascript to have a functioning site. It doesn't offer a gracious fallback.

Comment: A. If they can change anything (file names for example) so the site will works properly. B. They can show a message that the site is not working well with active adblock and if the user wants to full experiment, it will be better for disable it on SO.

Comment: Just exclude *.stackoverflow.com from being blocked by your adblock tool

Comment: Ya, I know and just did it. I thought about another users that will face this problem and wouldn't think about adblock issue.

Comment: there used to be a top banner when you had javascript blocked: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message. Can you check and [edit] in which resources failed to load? If the "requires javascript" banner no longer works that might be an unforeseen regression.

Comment: If you can whitelist cdn.sstatic.net instead of stackoverflow.com you should be good to go. sstatic.net is an SE owned domain so whitelisting it is considered to be safe, assuming you trust SE.

Comment: If I disable adblock on stackoverflow it's enough for me. Again, what about the other users who wouldn't think about adblock issue?

Comment: There are some `<noscript>` tags that try to inject generic CSS and a div that tells users the site is best used with javascript enabled but those obviously don't work well if there is a partial failure. A front-end dev needs to look into this and decide if it is possible to detect this state.

Comment: There are a lot of options to detect if adblock is enable, for example: https://www.detectadblock.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by an error in Easylist. See [GitHub](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/41eb1d2456a7f23fd8331ff9962f20686c4fa0bf#diff-4903e7590de76df1abe1703921a2c88b). All sites with an *N* anywhere have resources blocked, including cdn.sstatic.net.

It should be fixed now. Make sure to update Easylist to get the solution.

Comment: Thanks! How can I update Easylist? I don't run it locally so I need to wait until adblock will update it?

Comment: Most ad blockers have a settings page that allows you to do this. I'm not familiar with your specific blocker. If you can't figure it out, you can try asking that on [su], but it's usually easy.

Comment: Just synced and it solved the problem!

Comment: _N_ number of sites were affected by this bug.

Comment: @MoshFeu An alternative would be: click the ABP icon, choose "Options", go to the "Advanced" tab, and then in the "Filter lists" section click "Update all filter lists".